# apostrophe spell cheking problem in texstudio

Tags: spelling, apostrophe

i have an issue with the apostrophe of some words, well I'm writing a french document and when I do check spelling document it give me errors on word that has an apostrophe even the word is written correctly , for example :
   the word J’ai has an apostrophe not like the word J'ai and that cause me problems issue on spelling check it doesn't recognize the word, also I mention that the apostrophe in my keyboard is the correct one it has no issue with the editor, the problem is shown only when copy a word from outside in the editor.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) I would suggest you do a search and replace in your TeX document, search for the wrong apostrophe `’` and replace with the right apostrophe `'`. If you just copy paste chunks of text from, let's say, PDFs, it is most likely you will end up with `’` which is not well understood correctly by your editor. If you want to avoid that, just don't copy paste or run frequent search and replace with the apostrophes.

Comment: Well this solution doesn't work for me, but thank you any way